# How to release lock on fetched message from azure service bus queue using isPeekLock:true

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

In node, I am fetching azure service bus queue messages using the azure library
here is my code.

```
const azure = require('azure');
const serviceBusService = azure.createServiceBusService();

serviceBusService.receiveQueueMessage('queueName', { isPeekLock: true }, (error, lockedMessage) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log('Error', error)
    } else {
      console.log('Message', lockedMessage)
    }
  });
```

I am getting lockedMessage but I don't know how to release lock in this fetched message so other consumers can use that message and processed further.

I didn't find anything in azure documentation.

Comment: Are you using `azure-sb` node package or `@azure/service-bus` node package? I would like to say `azure-sb` but then `const azure = require('azure');` is something you would use with `@azure/service-bus` package.

Comment: I am using this(https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure) node package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the unlockMessage method to release the lock you acquire during peekLock.

Quoting below from this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-nodejs-how-to-use-queues#how-to-handle-application-crashes-and-unreadable-messages

> "Service Bus provides functionality to help you gracefully recover from errors in your
>   application or difficulties processing a message. If a receiver application is unable to  process the message for some reason, then it can call the unlockMessage method on the 
>   ServiceBusService object. it will cause Service Bus to unlock the message within the 
>   queue and make it available to be received again, either by the same consuming 
>   application or by another consuming application."